# Put codes into image.

Tags: image

I visited a site today. The site was well designed. I saw a man was holding a banner, The banner was about like us on Facebook. The Facebook like box was in the banner. How can he integrated the codes into an image? 
Is there any way to do that with adobe Dreamweaver or what so ever?
Please write in details.

Comment: [While you're visitng things, please visit our FAQ.](http://serverfault.com/faq)

Answer (score 1):

The HTML code used to do this is:

```
<a href="URL OF TARGET LOCATION" >
<img src="URL OF IMAGE"></a>
```